# Getting Error while trying to Index SVN Repository

Tags: c#, svn, indexing

I am getting the following errors when i am trying to index the SVN repository using SVN Index application provided by SVN Query.

-> When I give the root repository path as the input to the indexer i am getting the error

Error found -  URL 'http://SVN_Repository//Development/tags' is not a child of repository root URL 'http://SVN_Repository/'

-> When i give specific folder as a input to the indexer then i am getting the error

Error found - Unable to find repository location for 'http://SVN_Repository/DataCollection/trunk' in revision 1000.

Help about SVN query is available at the given link :-

http://svnquery.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=o0dpdE

I tried using "-s"  option (for Indexing a particular revision only) but i was getting the same issue again and again.

Can somebody help me in this regard.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer to the problem the main issue was with the Sharp SVN that was used in the project. We need sharp SVN 1.7 to work with it. So downloaded Sharp SVN latest dll's and it helped in completing the work.